# Refactoring: name of removing a superclass?

Tags: class, refactoring

For a school assignment, we've received a Java project, and we have been asked to refactor as much as possible, as long as it's good for code quality.

One of the things I've done, is removing a class. There was a class "Cab extends ImageIcon", and a class "Train extends Cab". But this inheritance had no specific use whatsoever (i.e. the class "Train" was the only one extending Cab). So eventually, I ended up with only "Train extends ImageIcon".

Now, in the documentation, we have to name our refactorings. We have a list (which I'll put on the bottom of this post) and the closest I've come is "Push down method" and "Push down field". But that didn't involve the constructor body of the superclass.

The list:

1. Pull up field
2. Pull up method
3. Pull up constructor body
4. Push down method
5. Push down field
6. Extract subclass
7. Extract superclass
8. Extract interface
9. Collapse hierarchy
10. Form template method
11. Replace inheritance with delegation
12. Replace delegation with inheritance

I hope any of you could help me. If my refactoring was a bad choice, please tell me! I'm fairly new in this kind of things.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it sounds like you collapsed the hierarchy.

The hierarchy used to be

```
ImageIcon
    ^
    |
   Cab
    ^
    |
  Train
```

And you've turned it into:

```
ImageIcon
    ^
    |
  Train
```

You've kinda merged the Cab class and the Train class into a new Train class, which made the hierarchy collapse.

Comment: Sounds logical to me. I've completely missed the meaning of the word "collapse" there, probably because I'm Dutch :-) but I think this is it. Thanks a lot!